# Error when trying to connect/send Access request to Freeradius server

Tags: freeradius, radius

I'm using **freeradius** on **docker** and is trying to get a response back when **access request** is sent.

When **radtest** is run using: *radtest bob testpw 127.0.0.1 1812 sharedSecret*

```
Sent Access-Request Id 18 from 0.0.0.0:56219 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
        User-Name = "bob"
        User-Password = "testpw"
        NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.0.2
        NAS-Port = 1812
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00
        Cleartext-Password = "testpw"
Sent Access-Request Id 18 from 0.0.0.0:56219 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
        User-Name = "bob"
        User-Password = "testpw"
        NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.0.2
        NAS-Port = 1812
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00
        Cleartext-Password = "testpw"
Sent Access-Request Id 18 from 0.0.0.0:56219 to 127.0.0.1:1812 length 73
        User-Name = "bob"
        User-Password = "testpw"
        NAS-IP-Address = 172.17.0.2
        NAS-Port = 1812
        Message-Authenticator = 0x00
        Cleartext-Password = "testpw"
(0) No reply from server for ID 18 socket 3
```

I know that this normally happens when the shared secret is wrong, but it is the same as mentioned in the configuration files.

When debugged I get the bellow error.

> Ignoring request to auth address * port 1812 bound to server default
>   from unknown client 172.17.0.3 port 60699 proto udp Ready to process
>   requests

error is given without any response back from the server.

The **clients.conf** file is as follows;

```
client dockernet {
    ipaddr = 172.17.0.0/16
    secret = sharedSecret
}
```

and **authorise** file;

```
bob Cleartext-Password := "testpw"
```

**default** file;

```
server default {
listen {

    type = auth

    ipv4addr = *
# ipv6addr = *
#   ipaddr = *

    port = 5

#   interface = eth0
#   clients = per_socket_clients

    recv_buff = 65536

    limit {
          max_connections = 16

          lifetime = 0

          idle_timeout = 30
    }
}
authorize {
    update request { 
        &Tmp-String-0 := "%{string:User-Password}" 
        &User-Password := "%{string:Tmp-String-0}" 
    } 

#   filter_username

#   filter_password

    preprocess

#   operator-name

#   cui

#   auth_log

    chap

    mschap

    digest

#   wimax

#   IPASS

    suffix
#   ntdomain

    eap {
        ok = return
#       updated = return
    }


    #
#   unix

    #  Read the 'users' file.  In v3, this is located in
    #  raddb/mods-config/files/authorize
    files

    -sql

#   smbpasswd

    -ldap

#   daily

    expiration
    logintime

    pap


#   Autz-Type Status-Server {
#   }
}
authenticate {
    ntlm_auth

    Auth-Type PAP {
        pap
    }

    Auth-Type CHAP {
        chap
    }

    Auth-Type MS-CHAP {
        mschap
    }

    mschap

    digest

#   pam

#   Auth-Type LDAP {
#       ldap
#   }

    #
    #  Allow EAP authentication.
    eap

#   Auth-Type eap {
#       eap {
#           handled = 1
#       }
#       if (handled && (Response-Packet-Type == Access-Challenge)) {
#           attr_filter.access_challenge.post-auth
#           handled  # override the "updated" code from attr_filter
#       }
#   }
}


#
#  Pre-accounting.  Decide which accounting type to use.
#
preacct {
    preprocess

    #
    #  Merge Acct-[Input|Output]-Gigawords and Acct-[Input-Output]-Octets
    #  into a single 64bit counter Acct-[Input|Output]-Octets64.
    #
#   acct_counters64

#   update request {
#       &FreeRADIUS-Acct-Session-Start-Time = "%{expr: %l - %{%{Acct-Session-Time}:-0} - %{%{Acct-Delay-Time}:-0}}"
#   }

    acct_unique

#   IPASS
    suffix
#   ntdomain

    #
    #  Read the 'acct_users' file
    files
}
```

An **Access-Accept** or an **Access-Reject** is expected. But no response, when debugged and gives the above error in the logs.

Comment: Your debug output doesn't make sense, you're sending packets to the loopback address, yet FreeRADIUS is complaining about packets coming from 172.17.0.3.

Comment: @ArranCudbard-Bell, neither do i understand why it doesn't respond back and, give that error. Do you think that i've done the configurations right? Or is there something that i'm not seeing?

Comment: I've edited my question a little bit, i'm sorry, I forgot to mention the output of radtest.

Comment: If it helps anyone, my issue was a misconfigure `client` section, where a `}` was misplaced, combining two sections together. Strangely there was no error starting the server, but it failed authentication with the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works! after I changed the **clients.conf** file to have a netmask and **not** `ipaddr = 172.17.0.0/16`

```
client dockernet {
    ipaddr = 172.17.0.0
    secret = sharedSecret
    netmask = 24
    shortname = dockernet
}
```

This article helped me https://linux.die.net/man/5/clients.conf